# Create Byte[] from DirectoryEntry C#

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, byte, directoryentry

Hello i have converted this example https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/VBGetUserGroupInAD-a94dc080 from VB .Net to C#
But i don't know how I can translate the following code row:

```
'Get the objectSID which is Byte array
Dim objectSid As Byte() = DirectCast(deTempForSID.Properties("objectSid").Value, Byte())
```

As I understod it have to be something like that, but i'm not sure, as it's not working and return array overflow:

```
byte[] objectSid = BitConverter.GetBytes(deTempForSID.Properties.Contains("objectSid"));
```

Plese can some one explain me how I can translate this code from VB .Net to C# correctly?

Comment: Why are you now converting Contains() instead of Value??  A *bool* is not a Sid.

Comment: So you just randomly typed something else?  Use `(byte[])deTempForSID.Properties["objectSid"].Value` instead.

Comment: **What** have you tried with `Value`? Array-indexers aren't parenthesis in C#, they're brackets (`[` and `]`).

Comment: `(byte[])deTempForSID.Properties["objectSid"].Value`... did you search for "DirectCast C#"?

Comment: Hans Passant, you correctly replied to my question firs, but I was not able to understand, as I was to tired... Can you put this row as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer, kindly suggested by Hans Passant is:

```
(byte[])deTempForSID.Properties["objectSid"].Value
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `Contains` returns a boolean. Use `Values` instead.